# Clojure in linux - REPL runs with different user?

Tags: linux, unix, clojure

I have some code in clojure that tries to switch the user at some point:

```
(sh "su" " - root" " -c" "/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin" :in "list-domains")
```

What I get is weird from my point of view:

```
{:exit 125, :out , :err su: user  - root does not exist}
```

Why can't I switch to user root? Is clojure running in a context that is unaware of the other users? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

su tries to make you the user named by the first argument, "- root".

Try separating it into "-" "root".